# Mysql with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, mysql, high-availability

I am converting a webapp from monolithic to kubernetes based architecture.
But how can mysql be persistent with data when we have 2 mysql pods in each of 2 differnet nodes?
I think we can mount a volume but still if my server with the mounted volume fails, this will be a single point of failure.
How can I avoid this?
I want to acheive no single point of failure using kubernetes without cloud.
How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to only run stateless apps in k8s. One should run statefull apps like databases in dedicated database solutions like AWS RDS.